# Trigger an action if CoreData NSPersistentContainer contents get modified, using KVO

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, key-value-observing

I'm building an iOS app using swift 4 and Core Data. My app contains a `tableView` whose elements are filled by data stored in Core Data. I want the tableView to reload automatically when data gets saved. I've considered using KVO, but I couldn't figure out a way to do it. I want to have the `AppDelegate`'s `persistentContainer` observed.

Comment: `NSFetchedResultsController` is your friend. It does the monitoring you're looking to implement.

Comment: Isn’t there a way for observing it using kvo? Cz the fetchcontoller doesn’t work for me

Answer (score 0):

Rather than working with the persistent container you should register for notifications from the [NSManagedObjectContext](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsmanagedobjectcontext) like [NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChange](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1506884-nsmanagedobjectcontextobjectsdid) to be notified when objects are changed or [NSManagedObjectContextDidSave](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1506380-nsmanagedobjectcontextdidsave) when objects have been saved.